# C# deserialization of JSON

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have this JSON string:

{"natalia1891":{"idUser":1435105,"nick":"natalia1891","sefNick":"natalia1891","status":1,"photo":"http:\/\/213.215.107.125\/fotky\/143\/51\/s_1435105.jpg?v=3","sex":2,"isFriend":1},

"pepina888":{"idUser":3338870,"nick":"pepina888","sefNick":"pepina888","status":1,"photo":"http:\/\/213.215.107.127\/fotky\/333\/88\/s_3338870.jpg?v=9","sex":2,"isFriend":1}}

I would like to deserialize this JSON into a dictionary of object Friend. Any advice?

maybe:

```
class Friend{

public string Name{get;set;}

public string IdUser{get;set;}

public string SefNick{get;set;}

public bool Status{get;set;}

public string Url{get;set;}

public int Sex{get;set;}

public bool isFriend{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.net) [documentation on serializing/deserializing](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializingJSON.html).

You *may* need to do a little work to effectively make it case-insensitive, although it [*looks* like James made it fairly forgiving a while ago](http://json.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=48776).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`JsonDataContractSerializer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) in the .Net framework.

Comment: An example on how to do this can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Friend[] friends = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Friend[]>(myString);
```

JavaScriptSerializer is in System.Web.Script.Serialization.